# ¿Cómo y cuál es el ciclo apropiado para resolver este problema?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo que realizar un ejercicio que me pide ingresar números y mostrar el máximo y el mínimo de ellos, esto ya lo hice, pero me pide que muestre la posición de ambos. Esto no se como hacerlo, si me pueden ayudar!!

```
num=int(input("Ingrese un numero:"))

if(num !=0):
    maximo = num


     minimo = num

        while(num!=0):
            cont=1
            if(num > maximo):
                maximo = num
            elif(num < minimo):
                minimo = num
            num=int(input("Ingrese un numero:"))
    print("El maximo es : ",maximo, "y el minimo es :",minimo)
```

Answer (score 2):

Es bastante parecido a lo que ya has hecho, la variable `cont` me hace pensar que los has intentado. Efectivamente necesitas llevar un contador de cada uno de los números ingresados y cuando detectas el nuevo `maximo` o `minimo`, así como guardas el número deberías guardar en otra variable la posición actual:

```
num=int(input("Ingrese un numero:"))
if(num !=0):
    maximo = num
    minimo = num
    cont=1
    pos_maximo = cont
    pos_minimo = cont

    while(num!=0):

        if(num > maximo):
            maximo = num
            pos_maximo = cont
        elif(num < minimo):
            minimo = num
            pos_minimo = cont

        cont=cont+1    
        num=int(input("Ingrese un numero:"))

    print("El maximo es: {0} en la posición {1}, y el mínimo: {2} en la {3}".format(maximo, pos_maximo, minimo, pos_minimo))
```

Notas:

- `pos_maximo` y `pos_minimo` son las variables que se llenan con el valor de `cont` que se actualiza por cada nuevo número ingresado.
- Para el `print` final, incorpore la idea de las [cadenas de formateo](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/), que son muy cómodas para organizar lo que vayas a imprimir

Comment: No funciona, si paso 100 y despues 1 me reconoce que el segundo es menor y la posicion 2, pero con respscto al primer valor no lo registra y me da error porque queda la variable pos_max sin utilizar.

Comment: @silvana, es cierto, me faltó inicializar `pos_maximo` y `pos_minimo` antes de entrar en el bucle, revisa la última edición.

Answer (score 0):

Sin desmerecer tu código y la solución propuesta, te muestro otra forma de hacerlo utilizando listas y funciones python:

```
 nums=[]
 while True:
     num=int(input("Ingrese un numero (0 para terminar):"))
     if num==0:
         break
     nums.append(num)

 if len(nums)    > 0:
      maximo=max(nums)
      minimo=min(nums)
      print("De  los numeros ingresados {}".format(nums))
      print("el maximo es {} poscion {}".format(maximo,nums.index(maximo)+1))
      print("el minimo es {} poscion {}".format(minimo,nums.index(minimo)+1))
```

Comment: Gracias, pero no puedo usar listas ni la funcion max ni la funcion min y a mi corrector  se le quemarian los ojos solo con ver el break.

Comment: la solución de Patricio Moracho es la más adecuada.